# Sharepoint q&a atleast 126 items

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a list of question and answer in sharepoint now is there any way that I will get result of that question and answer using calculated column,
Example I use this formula =SUM(if(exact(q1),(a1),1,0)) 
But there are atleast 126 question so it is very hectic job to create this for every column.

If any other way please let ke know

Comment: You need to explain this better. What is the formula supposed to do?

Comment: Well this formula will check whether the given selected option is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info in your question, so I'll make a few guesses and offer a few hints...

Your equation:

```
=SUM(if(exact(q1),(a1),1,0))
```

The EXACT function requires two parameters. Yours only shows one. Do you mean to write =SUM(if(exact(q1,a1),1,0))?

The SUM() in your example does not do anything useful as the result is still zero or one.

You did not mention a SharePoint version. If you are using 2007 and 2010 you will probably exceed the maximum formula length of 1024 characters. You could break this into multiple calculated columns and then summarize those.

Just guessing, but if your questions are in the form of 126 rows: you cannot use a Calculated Column to sum multiple rows. This can be done using a SharePoint 2013 workflow and REST API calls.

Just guessing, but if your questions are in the form of 126 columns and all must be answered correctly: you could write a formula like this:

```
=IF( 126 = if(exact([ColumnWithQuestion1],"AnswerForQuestion1"),1,0) +
           if(exact([ColumnWithQuestion2],"AnswerForQuestion3"),1,0) + 
           ...
           if(exact([ColumnWithQuestion126],"AnswerForQuestion126"),1,0)
```

As Boolean values can be treated as zeros (false) and ones (true), you can shorten the above to:

```
=IF( 126 = exact([ColumnWithQuestion1],"AnswerForQuestion1") +
           exact([ColumnWithQuestion2],"AnswerForQuestion3") + 
           ...
           exact([ColumnWithQuestion126],"AnswerForQuestion126")
```